# Creating a Table in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm reading through How to think Like a Scientist. Great book! I'm using Pycharm and I've been stumped on a couple of obstacles. When I try to run:

```
i = 1
while i <= 6:
    print(n * i, '\t',)
    i += 1
    print()
```

it only runs as a single line, but I want a table. This code is supposed to create a table where it shows the multiples of a given number. Yet, when I run it on Pycharm it gives the multiples of the number, but in a single line. Any and all assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please correct your indentation, you probably indented the wrong block

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of that code? It looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: first read the basic of python and indentation

Comment: Ok I fixed it, but that still doesn't solve my issue because it's still happening. Quite frankly I don't appreciate this community already except for Cluskii. I'm new to this community, I'm trying to figure out how to code because I really do feel like it's awesome, and I get down voted for asking questions?

Comment: @SkylerDavila downvot doesn't mean that community i harsh to you. It notes that your question lacks of research or unclear. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And community is dying to help newcommers. Welcome to SO! And cheers, mate!

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation to denote blocks of code (such as loops and conditionals). You need to indent the final three lines of code as such to get the loop to work:

```
i = 1
while i <= 6:
    print(n * i, '\t',)
    i += 1
    print()
```

You may wish to use a `for` loop here, which is perhaps a little bit more concise:

```
for i in range(0,6):
    print(n * i, '\t',)
    i += 1
    print()
```

You can read a little more about indentation denoting blocks here:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/design.html?highlight=indentation
http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk

Comment: I did that but it still prints in a single line, in chapter 6 I'm trying to create a two dimensional table and yet my Pycharm still prints in a single line even with the code you just entered. Really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: I even copy pasted your first and second input and my pycharm still entered in the outcome through a single line

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? I've tested the code and it works on my end.

Comment: when I use pycharm I just enter control +shift+ r because I'm on a Mac and thats the shortcut. Cluskii really do appreciate your input on this if I'm doing it wrong let me know

Comment: Are you saving the file before running it? And are you certain that your run configuration is running the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
while i <= 6:
    print(n * i, '\t',)
    i += 1
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.